# How can I establish an AVRCP connection from Windows 7 (controller) to phone (target) using L2CAP on Widcomm SDK?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, l2cap, avrcp

I am using the CL2Cap class in the Widcomm SDK on Win7. I am able to successfully establish the L2CAP connection and send the UNIT INFO command but the data returned is incorrect. I suspect that the stack has already established a connection and the AVRCP spec says:

> "Only one L2CAP connection shall be established between AVCTP entities. If the connection already exists, the CT/TG shall not initiate the connection request."

Can anyone shed some light on what could be the problem? I have verified that the stack can establish a connection directly and play media on from the phone, but I am unable to do this programmatically.