# Bluetooth AVRCP control from Windows

Tags: windows, bluetooth, l2cap, a2dp, avrcp

I'm trying to implement an AVRCP/A2DP connection between my Android phone and my car PC. The A2DP bit basically works out of the box so no issue there. I want the PC to be the AVRCP CT (controller) and the A2DP sink. The phone is the AVRCP TG (target) and the A2DP source.

Where I'm having trouble is getting any sort of AVRCP connection that I can use. Windows 7 comes with a toolbar application that at least provides the basic play/pause/skip/stop type functions. So it definitely works with the software I have without any extra drivers or otherwise. However my searching has produced little results on any way to do this or documentation on creating an L2CAP connection which I believe I need.

The 32feet.NET libraries don't support L2CAP connections unless you use a Broadcom/Widcomm stack. Buying a new BT USB device may be a viable solution but at the moment I'm trying to do this all in software :). i.e. like this although there a problems noted there that weren't solve (or reported as solved)
link: [How can I establish an AVRCP connection from Windows 7 (controller) to phone (target) using L2CAP on Widcomm SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997255/how-can-i-establish-an-avrcp-connection-from-windows-7-controller-to-phone-ta?rq=1)

I'd prefer to do it C# if possible but if I had some kind of library to interface with my code, that would be fine (like the 32feet.NET library which works quite well for the things it does work on.)

This is about the closest I've got but is all a bit Greek to me and not quite enough to get me started (I'm an embedded guy):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff536674(v=vs.85).aspx

Is Bluetooth really such a mess on Windows that it seems to be from my searching? There are multiple different stacks that all seem to be significantly different in terms of the API etc.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've done a lot of searching/reading other posts here and elsewhere and not really made any progress.

Thanks

Christian

Comment: Hello Christian, did you make any progress on this question. I am also interested in an answer.

Comment: Sorry, did not see the reply. I did not make any progress on this unfortunately. Windows just seems to make it too hard.